# Diferença entre _blank/_self e blank/self

Tags: html5

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma recomendação no uso dos atributos Html **target** com ou sem o **`_`** antes do valor, vejo que é meio que padrão utiliza-lo com  `_`, mas, se estiver ausente o redirecionamento também funciona:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Blank com _</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank">Blank sem _</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_self">Self com _</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="self">Self sem _</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O *undescore* (`_`) prefixado no `_blank` ou `_self` tem a função de indicar onde o link será aberto. O primeiro em uma nova aba, o segundo na própria aba.

O `_blank` indica que o link será aberto **sempre** numa nova aba, não importa quantas vezes ele for clicado: se você clicar 100 vezes, serão abertas 100 novas abas.

Se você omitir o `_`, usando apenas `blank`, o target perde a função específica e vira apenas um alvo comum, significando que você está abrindo uma nova aba com o nome "blank". Então, sempre que você clicar no link, o navegador irá verificar se já tem uma aba aberta com esse nome. Se tiver, ele carrega o link na aba já aberta, se não, abre uma nova. O mesmo vale pro `target="self"`, ou `target="qualquercoisa"` etc.

Comment: Valeu Sam, muito interessante isto, realmente nem imaginava que existiam estas funcionalidades.

Answer (score 5):

Sobre `underscore` (*underline*) veja que segundo essa documentação da W3C ele deve preceder palavras chaves especiais reservadas. Sem ele a *string* é como uma *string* normal e é interpretada de forma diferente pelo browser https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/browsers.html#browsing-context-names

> A valid browsing context name is any string with at least one character that does not start with a [U+005F](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005f/index.htm) LOW LINE character. (Names starting with an underscore are reserved for special keywords.)

PORTUGUÊS
"*Um nome de contexto de navegação válido é qualquer string com pelo menos um caractere que não comece com um caractere U + 005F LOW LINE. (Os nomes que começam com um sublinhado são reservados para palavras-chave especiais.)*"

[U+005F](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005f/index.htm) Unicode Character 'LOW LINE' <kbd>_</kbd>

No entanto no próprio validador de HTML da W3C o código passou sem problemas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faça o teste https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Outra curiosidade é que esse atributo é `case-insensitive` https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110525/datatypes.html#common.data.browsing-context-name-or-keyword-def

Comment: Legal Hugo, muito obrigado!