# Link abrir em outra página

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um botão em um formulario que é responsavel por gerar um relatório, porém preciso que esse relatório seja gerado em outra pagina. O botão é montado da seguinte maneira.

```
<a title=\"Gerar relatório\" href=\"'+$('#base-url').val()+'/relatorio/gerar_relatorio/'+v.cod+'\"></a>
```

E esta funcionando normal, preciso só que ele abra uma nova aba ao invés de executar na mesma.

Comment: Coloca um `target="_blank"` na tag `<a>`.

Comment: Tem uma resposta sua sobre isso né @Sam ? Passa o link para ele.

Comment: Aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349963/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-blank-self-e-blank-self

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Isso mesmo! 

Comment: Obrigado pessoal.