# Abrir uma guia diferente para cada link

Tags: html

Olá!

Estou começando a aprender HTML agora e me deparei com a seguinte situação: ao selecionar um dos links do body abro uma nova guia e ao selecionar o outro link é aberta uma nova guia que substitui a anterior.

O comportamento que gostaria de reproduzir é que a cada link clicado fosse aberta uma nova guia.

Como posso fazer isso usando o html?

Obs.: Qualquer dica ou instrução de boas práticas é bem vindo.

Abaixo um código exemplo que estou usando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>Exemplo 04</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href = "icone.png"/>
        <base href = "http://www.w3c.org/"/>
        <base target="_blank/"/>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color: lightpink;
            }
            
            p{
                color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Título do conteúdo</h1>
        <p>Link - padrões: <a href="/standards/">link</a></p>
        <p>Link - google: <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a></p>
    </body> 


</html>
```

Desde já grata!

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui que pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349963/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-blank-self-e-blank-self

Answer (score 4):

Olá, tudo bem?
Também sou novo em HTML 5 mas creio que sei a resposta. Para abrir o link em uma nova guia, basta adicionar o atributo **target=""** dentro da tag `<a>`, desta forma:

```
<p>Link - padrões: <a href="/standards/" target="_blank">link</a></p>
```

Nesse caso, preenchemos o target com **_blank** para abrir o link em uma nova aba em **branco** (acho que daí que veio o nome).
O padrão, se você não especifica e não coloca **_blank**, é o **_self**, no qual o link abre na mesma página.

Eu uso o VSCode para programar e nele já mostra as diversas funcionalidades dentro do atributo **target=""**, mas encontrei um artigo em inglês que fala sobre isso:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/target

Esse site de developers da Mozilla é muito bom (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/), eu recomendo pois além de uma boa documentação, existem alguns documentos em português do Brasil. Enfim, existem mais alguns usos para esse atributo, mas creio que para o que você está querendo fazer é isso. Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa tarde!
Basta que você adicione dentro da sua tag `<a>` o atributo **target="_blank"**, assim:

```
  <p>Link - padrões: <a href="/standards/" target = "_blanck">link</a></p>
```

Desta forma você está dizendo ao navegador que ao ser clicado o hyperlink tem como alvo (target) um nova aba em branco (blank).

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>Exemplo 04</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href = "icone.png"/>
        <base href = "http://www.w3c.org/"/>
        <base target="_blank/"/>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color: lightpink;
            }
            
            p{
                color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Título do conteúdo</h1>
        <p>Link - padrões: <a href="/standards/" target="_blank">link</a></p>
        <p>Link - google: <a href="http://www.google.com" target="blank">link</a></p>
    </body> 


</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Bons estudos!